# How to convert a Dell Service Tag to an Express Service Code Using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have all my Dell tags in Excel. I want to convert the short one to the long one.
I need to convert the small code to a BigDecimal, can this be done in Excel.

for Example:

```
So Simple

Typical Service Tag 5RFDP01 
Its Express Service Code
125-423-316-01

The dashes are the only thing that might throw you.

The Service Tag is just a big base-36 number (composed of digits [0-9A-Z]) so,
Convert it to a big decimal number (12,542,331,601), then
Add dashes every third digit starting from the left-most (MSD) digit
(This step is not necessary, but really does make the number a little easier to use.)
```

Comment: This looks more like a question on how to use MS Excel than about system administration and the reverse of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674345/

Comment: What have you attempted? Please share what you have in Excel so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit convoluted, but this is possible in a formula even if you do not have the `DECIMAL` function available to use.  The following formula will accomplish this:

```
= (IFERROR(MID(A1,1,1) + 55, CODE(MID(A1,1,1))) - 55) * 36^6
+ (IFERROR(MID(A1,2,1) + 55, CODE(MID(A1,2,1))) - 55) * 36^5
+ (IFERROR(MID(A1,3,1) + 55, CODE(MID(A1,3,1))) - 55) * 36^4
+ (IFERROR(MID(A1,4,1) + 55, CODE(MID(A1,4,1))) - 55) * 36^3
+ (IFERROR(MID(A1,5,1) + 55, CODE(MID(A1,5,1))) - 55) * 36^2
+ (IFERROR(MID(A1,6,1) + 55, CODE(MID(A1,6,1))) - 55) * 36^1
+ (IFERROR(MID(A1,7,1) + 55, CODE(MID(A1,7,1))) - 55) * 36^0
```

The `IFERROR` function requires Excel 2007 or higher.  Furthermore, this formula assumes that your service tag is in cell A1.

To obtain the proper formatting, you can use a custom format like CharlieRB stated in another answer: `###-###-###-##`

Answer (score 2):

Excel 2013 has the capability to perform this using the [`DECIMAL`](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/DECIMAL-function-ee554665-6176-46ef-82de-0a283658da2e) function.

This example assumes your Service Tag values are in column A. Place this formula where you what the Express Service Code to be.

```
=DECIMAL(A1, 36)
```

This formulas tells Excel 2013 the number in `A1` is a *base 36* and to convert it to the equivalent decimal value.

You will have to custom format the cells in the column to `###-###-###-##`